# WCF WS throwing MaxReceivedMessageSizeExceeded

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF web service that is accepting some custom objects and a number of documents sent as byte arrays.

But each time I send a document (not a particularly large one) the WS returns a 400 bad request, and in the trace log it appears to have thrown a `MaxReceivedMessageSizeExceeded`.
saying

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException:
>   The maximum message size quota for
>   incoming messages (65536) has been
>   exceeded. To increase the quota, use
>   the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on
>   the appropriate binding element.

Now the client app has this in its `app.config`

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IReferrals" 
        closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" 
        receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" 
        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
        allowCookies="false">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
            maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
```

and in the WCF `web.config` I have this

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="WCFReferrals.Service1Behavior"
        name="WCFReferrals.Referrals">
     <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFReferrals.IReferrals">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
     </endpoint>
     <endpoint address="mex" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
 </service>
 ....
 <binding name="wsHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
            maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
 </binding>
```

Clearly I am missing something as as far as I can see I have all the max message limits set waaaaay over what is necessary..

Any help would be happily received

thanks

nat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: on your server side, you **define** the binding configuration with larger message size, but you **don't reference** it from your endpoint.

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="WCFReferrals.Service1Behavior"
         name="WCFReferrals.Referrals">
   <endpoint 
         address="" 
         binding="wsHttpBinding" 
         bindingConfiguration="LargeSizeMessages"  <== you need to reference the binding config (by specifying its name
        contract="WCFReferrals.IReferrals">
    </endpoint>
    .....
  </service>
  ....
  <binding name="LargeSizeMessages"   <== give it a meaningful name
       maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
       <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
           maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
           maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
  </binding>
```

Also: are you doing the same thing on your client-side? Does your client-side config (`app.config` or `web.config`) also include that large message size binding configuration? Are you *referencing* that binding configuration in your `<client> .. <endpoint>` element??

Comment: am totally new to this and that worked a treat. i guess i was thinking that the binding property pointed at the binding you wanted. not the bindingconfiguration. thanks very much indeed.

Comment: @nat: you could have any number of binding configurations for a single binding - that's why you need to reference the one you want for your endpoint by its name