# WCF Service Error 413 Entity Too Large

Tags: wcf

Need some insight on where to look further related to a WCF error I am getting about the Request Entity Too Large (Error 413).

Pretty much, the service is a simple [OperationContract] accepting a string as a parameter.

```
<IService.cs>
[OperationContract]
string UploadReportText(string ReportText);


<Service.cs>
public string UploadReportText(string ReportText)
{
  // Code to process data passed.
}
```

I've already set the web config for the service as follows:

```
<bindings>
 <webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
   </binding>
 </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Although I believe the uploadReadAhead value in IIS needs not be touched (as I am not using SSL), I still modified it to have a value of 2147483647.

Tracing one of the apps that call the service in Chrome, I can see that the data Content-Length is 169786.

Really stumped where to look further related to this.

Appreciate any insight. Thanks

Update: 
Additional Info
If I set the string data being passed to the service to a smaller length, I am not getting an error. Most of the search I did related to this all points to the maxReceivedMessageSize needs to be adjusted to the maximum possible value, but setting it in the web config seems to have no effect.

**Update:**
Enabled logging and I got this message:

Exception details: `System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all: on your server side, you define the binding configuration with larger message size, but you don't reference it from your endpoint.

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFReferrals.Service1Behavior"
             name="WCFReferrals.Referrals">
       <endpoint 
             address="" 
             binding="wsHttpBinding" 
             bindingConfiguration="LargeSizeMessages"  <== you need to reference the binding config (by specifying its name
            contract="WCFReferrals.IReferrals">
        </endpoint>
        .....
      </service>
      ....
      <binding name="LargeSizeMessages"   <== give it a meaningful name
           maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
               maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
               maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </binding>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337367/wcf-ws-throwing-maxreceivedmessagesizeexceeded)

[Refer this too](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/872fff1e-b78e-4b49-808c-558f46a11a17/the-maximum-message-size-quota-for-incoming-messages-65536-has-been-exceeded-to-increase-the?forum=wcf)

Comment: binding configuration= "LargeSizeMessages" did the trick after trying many solutions

Answer (score 0):

Also need to do the same thing on your client-side as well. Does your client-side config (`app.config` also include that large message size binding configuration.

Comment: For simplicity and consistency, yes.  But if the client is not receiving large responses back, then technically the larger value does not need to be set.

Answer (score 0):

As Vignesh said, you don't have a name assigned to your defined binding.  This makes it the default configuration for that binding (in WCF 4.0+ later), so you actually have two choices.  You can give it a name, create an explicit endpoint and reference it via the `bindingCongifuration`, per Vignesh's suggestion.

Or, you can use the `<proctolMapping>` part of the `<system.serviceModel>` section to assign the `webHttpBinding` as the default binding for `http` (the normal WCF default binding for http is `basicHttpBinding`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <protocolMapping>
    <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
  </protocoalMapping>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This goes in your service's config file.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just needed to add this chunk to my **web.config**:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647777" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

My **web.config** was already using the `webHttpBinding` binding (as shown below), it just needed this `<bindings>` section to allow it to upload large files.

```
<services>
    <service name="PocketCRMServices.Service1">
      <endpoint address="../Service1.svc"
        binding="webHttpBinding"
        contract="PocketCRMServices.IService1"
        behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" />
    </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# In my case I had the following configuration.


- Four final points.
- 
    

<endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding"
                contract="MSService.IService"
                behaviorConfiguration="web"
                bindingConfiguration="webhttpsBinding"/>

    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="Service"
      contract="MSService.IService" />
      
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpsBinding" name="Service"
      contract="MSService.IService" />
      
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />

- A definite link
- 
   

 <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webhttpsBinding">
            <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>

- A protocolMapping section

    

 <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>

I set up the only bindig, with
        
 

   maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647                        maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647

And finally I added the readeQuotas section

    

<readerQuotas maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>

My configuration is:

 

<bindings><webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webhttpsBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
                <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```